# Calculating average fps for a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, frame-rate

I'm trying to calculate the average fps during my app's lifetime, I need the print logs to show up after terminating the app but it does not appear. What seems to be the problem in this code? I need these logs to benchmark some information about flutter's performance, if there's any other easier way please inform me.

```
class _LazyLoadingState extends State<LazyLoading>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver, SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  StreamController<CellData>? _streamController;
  
  //Frame rate stuff
  Duration _elapsed = Duration.zero;
  late Ticker _ticker;
  int _frameCount = 0;
  double _frameRate = 0.0;
  double _totalElapsedTime = 0.0;
  double _averageFrameRate = 0.0;

  List<double> _frameRates = [];
  double _minFrameRate = double.infinity;
  double _maxFrameRate = 0.0;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamController = StreamController<CellData>();
    startGeneratingNumbers();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _verticalScrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    _ticker = createTicker((elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        _frameCount++;
        _frameRate = _frameCount / elapsed.inSeconds;
        if (elapsed.inSeconds >= 1) {
          // Calculate average frame rate
          _totalElapsedTime += elapsed.inSeconds;
          _averageFrameRate = _frameCount / _totalElapsedTime;
          // Reset frame count
          _frameCount = 0;

          // Track frame rate in the list
          _frameRates.add(_frameRate);

          // Update min and max frame rates
          if (_frameRate < _minFrameRate) {
            _minFrameRate = _frameRate;
          }
          if (_frameRate > _maxFrameRate) {
            _maxFrameRate = _frameRate;
          }
        }
      });
    });
    _ticker.start();
  }

 

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController?.close();
    _horizontalScrollController.dispose();
    _verticalScrollController.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);

    _ticker.dispose();
    print('Min Frame Rate: $_minFrameRate fps');
    print('Max Frame Rate: $_maxFrameRate fps');
    print('Average Frame Rate: $_averageFrameRate fps');


    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: check this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addTimingsCallback.html